# SQL Insert without knowing all of the values for a new row

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have a table with 5 columns and I'd like to insert a new row. The problem is, I do not yet have the values for all 5 columns.

Is it possible to add information to the first and third columns and add the rest later?

This is not referring to a specific database management system. I'd just like to know if it's possible.

Comment: Yes, you can set the columns that you want to leave empty to be nullable. Then you can insert a new row with their values set to NULL. When you have the values for them you can just run an update query.

Comment: Yes it is possible to insert only first and third columns if remaining columns are nullable then you could use null for those columns while inserting and update them later when you get the actual values for these columns.

Comment: `insert into the_table (column_two, column_five) values ('two', 'five');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, it's not.

However, you can insert dummy values (like `NULL`s or defaults) into the problem columns and then update them later when you know the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your table definition, if column accept null value you don't have to provide a value for it in insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on table definition.
Some tables require value by design, other not.
It is also worth to mention, that database may be configured to throw error when required fields are not set. In other cases there is only warning and fields are initialized by NULL value despite being defined as "NOT NULL".

Some of fields cannot be omitted at all. Those are mainly primary key fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes u could do that as follow (MS SQL Server):

```
CREATE TABLE #TM
([ID]   INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
 [Col1] INT,
 [Col2] VARCHAR(MAX),
 [Col3] VARCHAR(MAX),
 [Col4] VARCHAR(MAX),
 [Col5] VARCHAR(MAX)
);
INSERT INTO #TM
([Col1],
 [Col3]
)
       SELECT '1',
              '2';
```

Later, you could update the Data in rest of columns with help of `ID` Column (i.e. unique identity column) which is auto increment.

However, it would insert `NULL` values in other columns which are not defined in column list.